# Grayscale video file corrupted in OpenCV3.3, MJPG codec

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, raspberry-pi

My setup is using a logitech c920, raspberry pi 3, and the latest opencv 3.3. I am showing in screen and writing in a file the camera stream. The only processing I am doing is converting video to grayscale. In the screen all show good, but the file is corrupted (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHrQb.png).

Noticeable, the video is well recorded in XVID, and also in MJPG if the original color image is selected instead.

UPDATE: I tested the same code in os-x and the same error happens, also with opencv3.3

Any advice welcome :)

This is the code:

```cpp
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {

    int FPS = 10;
    int nframes;
    double start, now;

    VideoCapture vcap(0);
    if(!vcap.isOpened()) {
            cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << endl;
            return 0;
    }

    vcap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC,CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'));

    int frame_width = vcap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    int frame_height = vcap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    VideoWriter video("out.avi",CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'), FPS, Size(frame_width,frame_height), false);

    namedWindow("Main",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called

    // Start time
    start = (double)getTickCount();
    for(;;) {
            Mat frame, gray;
            vcap >> frame;
            cvtColor(frame, gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            video << gray;
            imshow("Main", gray);

            char c = (char)waitKey(2);
            if( c == 27 ) break;

            ++nframes;
            if (nframes==100) {
                    now = (double)getTickCount();
                    cout << "FPS: " << ++nframes/(now-start)*getTickFrequency() << endl;
                    start = now;
                    nframes = 0;
            }
    }
    video.release();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I may be wrong, and am happy to be corrected if so proven... but I don't think `ffmpeg` (which I believe is what OpenCV uses underneath) supports writing greyscale MJPEG... https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4116

Comment: Your corrupt file also looks to be about 1/3 of a frame of useful data, like it is one sensible channel and two channels of whatever was in memory after the single grey channel you gave it where it was expecting two further channels of data.

Comment: Umm... depends on the frame, some others have a different pattern. E.g. https://imgur.com/a/eq3KH
https://imgur.com/a/vbiUO